# How to register a stateless processor (that seems to require a StateStore as well)?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building a topology and want to use [KStream.process()](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorSupplier,%20java.lang.String...)) to write some intermediate values to a database. This step doesn't change the nature of the data and is completely stateless.

Adding a [Processor](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html) requires to create a [ProcessorSupplier](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorSupplier.html) and pass this instance to the `KStream.process()` function along with the name of a state store. This is what I don't understand.

How to add a [StateStore](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateStore.html) object to a topology since it requires a [StateStoreSupplier](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateStoreSupplier.html)?

Failing to add a said `StateStore` gives this error when the application is started:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyBuilderException: Invalid topology building: StateStore my-state-store is not added yet.

Why is it necessary for a processor to have a state store? It seems that this could well be optional for processors that are stateless and don't maintain state.

> Process all elements in this stream, one element at a time, by applying a Processor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a [simple example on how to use state stores](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#processor-api), taken from the [Confluent Platform documentation on Kafka Streams](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/).

**Step 1: Defining the `StateStore`/`StateStoreSupplier`:**

```
StateStoreSupplier countStore = Stores.create("Counts")
                                      .withKeys(Serdes.String())
                                      .withValues(Serdes.Long())
                                      .persistent()
                                      .build();
```

> 1. I don't see a way to add a StateStore object to my topology. It requires a StateStoreSupplier as well though.

**Step 2: Adding the state store to your topology.**

Option A - When using the Processor API:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

// add the source processor node that takes Kafka topic "source-topic" as input
builder.addSource("Source", "source-topic")
       .addProcessor("Process", () -> new WordCountProcessor(), "Source")
       // Add the countStore associated with the WordCountProcessor processor
       .addStateStore(countStore, "Process")
       .addSink("Sink", "sink-topic", "Process");
```

Option B - When using the Kafka Streams DSL:

Here you need to call `KStreamBuilder#addStateStore("name-of-your-store")` to add the state store to your processor topology.  Then, when calling methods such as `KStream#process()` or `KStream#transform()`, you must also pass in the name of the state store -- otherwise your application will fail at runtime.

At the example of `KStream#transform()`:

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

// Add the countStore that will be used within the Transformer[Supplier]
// that we pass into `transform()` below.
builder.addStateStore(countStore);

KStream<byte[], String> input = builder.stream("source-topic");

KStream<String, Long> transformed =
    input.transform(/* your TransformerSupplier */, countStore.name());
```

> Why is it necessary for a processor to have a state store? It seems that this could well be optional for processors that are stateless and don't maintain state.

You are right -- you don't need a state store if your processor does not maintain state.

When using the DSL, you need to simply call `KStreamBuilder#addStateStore("name-of-your-store")` to add the state store to your processor topology and reference it later on.

Comment: I recall seeing this (and similar) but Im not using **TopologyBuilder**. Am trying to work through this using `.foreach()`.

Comment: You can't use state stores in the DSL's `foreach()` operator because, by definition of the operator, `foreach()` adds a *stateless* processor node to the topology.  But you can use `transform()`, `transformValues()`, and `process()` in the DSL for stateful operations.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams%3A+Internal+Data+Management.

Comment: And sorry I missed that you are using the DSL.  There's a `process()` method in both the DSL and the Processor API. :-)